# Named Exception Calling using PRAGMA

Tags: oracle, plsql

Certainly! Here's a question you can post on Stack Overflow:

---

**Title: Handling Exception in Oracle PL/SQL when SELECT into Variable**

**Body:**

I'm working on an Oracle PL/SQL block where I'm trying to retrieve a product ID (`prodid`) from a table (`catalog1`) based on a given `sid`. I'm using the following code snippet:

```sql
DECLARE
    ct_exception EXCEPTION;
    prodid NUMBER(22);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ct_exception, -2293);
BEGIN
    SELECT c.pid INTO prodid FROM catalog1 c WHERE sid = &a;

    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        RAISE ct_exception;
    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN ct_exception THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record not found');
END;
```

However, even when there is no record found for the specified `sid`, it doesn't seem to be raising the exception as expected. I'm relatively new to PL/SQL, so any insights into what might be going wrong or alternative approaches to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your client/IDE configured to show `dbms_output`? eg `set serveroutput on` in SQL\*Plus and related tools? (And why do you appear to have asked ChatGPT to generate a question for you - is this actually a problem you are having? Why are you catching the exception at all, or using your own on top of the built-in one?)

Comment: Another example showing how stupid ChatGPT is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this question was generated by ChatGPT then the suggested title *Handling Exception in Oracle PL/SQL when SELECT into Variable* is more specific than the title you used (although *"in Oracle PL/SQL"* would be redundant as we have tags for that). Please don't include the whole "Certainly!" chat in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The correct implementation would be as simple as this:

```
DECLARE
    prodid NUMBER(22);
BEGIN
    SELECT c.pid INTO prodid FROM catalog1 c WHERE sid = &a;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record not found');
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

When there is no record found your code will never reach the If statement because Oracle will raise NO_DATA_FOUND Exception on Select Into statement. So your code could be like here

```sql
DECLARE
    prodid NUMBER(22);
BEGIN
    SELECT c.pid INTO prodid FROM catalog1 c WHERE sid = &a;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUNDTHEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record not found');
END;
```

Look at small example at https://dbfiddle.uk/KZi_-goE

Answer (score 0):

2293 is [Cannot validate check constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-02293/) when altering a table, which isn't going to arise when selecting into a variable. I recommend naming your exceptions in a way that reflects the expected exception rather than something generic like `ct_exception`. But you don't need a pragma here anyway as `no_data_found` is already defined, so you can use that directly in your exception handler.

[`sql%notfound`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-87C3CAFD-625D-4785-A32F-14E2440335DC) is useful for DML statements such as `update` or `delete` that may or may not affect any rows but don't fail if there are no rows to process.